# Maven emma has error but the tests are passing

Tags: maven, emma

my junit test are passing when i am running

```
mvn test
```

but

```
mvn emma:emma
```

it has errors.
How can i find out which classes are executed?
The errors that i have are related to spring

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.resolveContextLoader(ContextLoaderUtils.java:87)
```

since the same config is working fine, i think that there are some problems with the classpath when i run emma.
Any advice is apreciated,
10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spring-test version disagrees with your spring-beans version. Use `mvn dependency:tree` to find what's pulling in the relevant versions and use explicit top-level dependencies or dependency exclusions to manage them.

Comment: thank you for the advice, it was a dependency of org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE to  org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE after i excluded the 3.0.6 version is working, but i don't understand why is working when i run only the test; what dose emma:emma  to the classpath so that the error is caused?

Comment: The answer to that lies in the complete stack trace of the exception you got. It was causing some method to be called that had changed between Spring version. This kind of thing just pops up in random places when you have versioning problems.